# Is it a good practice to pass db connection as parameter to methods?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, database-connection

I am writing Python application to operate on Postgres database with SQLAlchemy. Specified the database information in a `settings.py`

```
DATABASE = {
    'drivername': 'postgres',
    'host': 'xyz.com',
    'port': '5432',
    'username': 'user',
    'password': 'pass',
    'database': 'db_dev'
}
```

Then I created a `db_connection.py` with a method to create a connection.

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL

from . import settings

def get_engine():
    return create_engine(URL(**settings.DATABASE))
```

I want to have another module `db_ops.py` that has all the database operation `func1`, `func2` methods and call them in the main application module

```
engine = db.connection.get_engine()
db_ops.func1()
db_ops.func2()
```

And that means I will need to pass `engine` as a parameter to these methods.

```
func1(engine)
func2(engine)
```

Somehow I don't like the idea of making db connection as method parameter. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: "I don't like the idea of making db connection as method parameter", why don't you like that?

Comment: @Cyzanfar I don't know. I program mostly with Java and Spring which you don't deal with database connection explicitly on the methods level. I thought it is bad to pass connection like this in Python.

Comment: I think it's fine. I don't think it's a good practice to refer to the db configs within the function. I'd rather pass it as a parameter

Comment: `db_connection.py` should have a executed live connection `conn = get_engine()`, and this `conn` should be imported by other files/functions. You will call ops1() or ops2() and these ops1 / ops2 will import conns.

Comment: @harshil9968 so add `global conn = get_engine()` in `db_connection.py` and `from db_connection import conn`. Like that?

Comment: I don't think you need to make it global, yeah the rest is what I recommend.

Comment: @harshil9968 I added `conn = get_engine()` before `def get_engine()` in `db_connection.py` got the error `unresolved reference 'get_engine'`

Comment: add that line after declaration of get_engine().

Comment: @harshil9968 when is the connection opened though? If I use db_connection.conn in multiple functions, does that mean the db reconnects every time `conn` is used? Or the connection is established during the import?

Comment: The connection will be opened on initialisation of `conn = get_engine()`. `conn` is the opened connection, when you import it's just that one opened connection being used again.

Comment: @harshil9968 do I need to worry about closing the connection after I'm done with it at all?

Answer (score 1):

An `Engine` is **not** a connection. You can think of it as a connection pool. Usually the most natural way to to use an engine is to put it at the global level. In your case, you can put it in `db_connection.py`:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL

from . import settings

engine = create_engine(URL(**settings.DATABASE))
```

Then, you can import it in your `db_ops` module:

```
from db_connection import engine

def func1():
    engine.execute(...)
```

However, for a series of related queries you probably want to execute them in a single transaction, which necessitates passing around the actual connection:

```
with engine.begin() as connection:
    func1(connection)
    func2(connection)
```

To solve this problem, we have the concept of a [`scoped_session`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html) (again, also at the global level):

```
engine = create_engine(URL(**settings.DATABASE))
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
```

Each time `Session` is called, it checks to see if there's already a session for the current thread, and creates it if it doesn't, obviating the need to pass around the connection:

```
from db_connection import Session

def func1():
    Session.execute(...)
```

In the caller of `db_ops` functions:

```
try:
    func1()
    func2()
    Session.commit()
finally:
    Session.remove()
```